# Данные из Json ( С# )

Tags: c#, json, webhook, .net-8

Как можно получить данные из вебхука ?

```json
[
    {
        "id": 429947782,
        "category_id": 35304067,
        "created_at": "2024-03-30T12:46:48.000+03:00",
        "updated_at": "2024-03-30T12:46:49.000+03:00",
        "is_hidden": false,
        "available": true,
        "archived": false,
        "canonical_url_collection_id": null,
        "custom_template": null,
        "unit": "pce",
        "sort_weight": null,
        "ignore_discounts": null,
        "vat": -1,
        "dimensions": null,
        "fiscal_product_type": 1,
        "title": "del",
        "short_description": null,
        "permalink": "del",
        "html_title": null,
        "meta_keywords": null,
        "meta_description": null,
        "currency_code": "RUR",
        "collections_ids": [],
        "sales_channels_id": null,
        "description": null,
        "images": [],
        "video_links": [],
        "option_names": [],
        "properties": [
            {
                "id": 56148852,
                "position": 22,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": true,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "est-na-ozone",
                "title": "Есть на Озоне"
            }
        ],
        "characteristics": [
            {
                "id": 235058051,
                "property_id": 56148852,
                "position": 1,
                "title": "0",
                "permalink": "0"
            }
        ],
        "product_field_values": [
            {
                "id": 402805292,
                "product_field_id": 88406,
                "value": "ptkG9EksjzVOEJNkm41Re3"
            }
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 714704791,
                "title": "",
                "product_id": 429947782,
                "sku": null,
                "barcode": null,
                "dimensions": null,
                "available": true,
                "image_ids": [],
                "image_id": null,
                "weight": null,
                "created_at": "2024-03-30T12:46:48.000+03:00",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-30T12:46:48.000+03:00",
                "quantity": null,
                "cost_price": null,
                "cost_price_in_site_currency": null,
                "price_in_site_currency": "0.0",
                "base_price": "0.0",
                "old_price": null,
                "price": "0.0",
                "base_price_in_site_currency": "0.0",
                "old_price_in_site_currency": null,
                "prices": [],
                "prices_in_site_currency": [],
                "variant_field_values": [
                    {
                        "id": 95118100,
                        "variant_field_id": 11800,
                        "value": "ptkG9EksjzVOEJNkm41Re3"
                    }
                ],
                "option_values": []
            }
        ],
        "product_bundle_components": []
    },
    {
        "id": 429947870,
        "category_id": 35304067,
        "created_at": "2024-03-30T12:47:12.000+03:00",
        "updated_at": "2024-03-30T12:47:13.000+03:00",
        "is_hidden": false,
        "available": false,
        "archived": false,
        "canonical_url_collection_id": null,
        "custom_template": null,
        "unit": "pce",
        "sort_weight": null,
        "ignore_discounts": null,
        "vat": -1,
        "dimensions": null,
        "fiscal_product_type": 1,
        "title": "del",
        "short_description": null,
        "permalink": "del-2",
        "html_title": null,
        "meta_keywords": null,
        "meta_description": null,
        "currency_code": "RUR",
        "collections_ids": [],
        "sales_channels_id": null,
        "description": null,
        "images": [],
        "video_links": [],
        "option_names": [],
        "properties": [
            {
                "id": 36075381,
                "position": 15,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": true,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "rekomendatsiya-na-otzyv",
                "title": "Рекомендация на отзыв"
            },
            {
                "id": 36743813,
                "position": 17,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": false,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "proizvoditel",
                "title": "Производитель"
            },
            {
                "id": 36743814,
                "position": 18,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": false,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "srok-godnostidata-izgotovleniya",
                "title": "Срок годности\\дата изготовления:"
            },
            {
                "id": 55615457,
                "position": 21,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": true,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "brend-3",
                "title": "Бренд"
            },
            {
                "id": 56148852,
                "position": 22,
                "is_hidden": false,
                "is_navigational": true,
                "backoffice": false,
                "permalink": "est-na-ozone",
                "title": "Есть на Озоне"
            }
        ],
        "characteristics": [
            {
                "id": 235058051,
                "property_id": 56148852,
                "position": 1,
                "title": "0",
                "permalink": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": 228900155,
                "property_id": 36075381,
                "position": 2,
                "title": "Оставьте отзыв на наш товар, это поможет нам стать лучше!",
                "permalink": "ostavte-otzyv-na-nash-tovar-eto-pomozhet-nam-stat-luchshe-2"
            },
            {
                "id": 147156384,
                "property_id": 36743813,
                "position": 1,
                "title": "nn",
                "permalink": "nn"
            },
            {
                "id": 231083733,
                "property_id": 55615457,
                "position": 2,
                "title": "n",
                "permalink": "n"
            },
            {
                "id": 233177122,
                "property_id": 36743814,
                "position": 151,
                "title": "Дата изготовления: 05.02.2024\nСрок годности: не ограничен",
                "permalink": "data-izgotovleniya-05022024-srok-godnosti-ne-ogranichen"
            }
        ],
        "product_field_values": [
            {
                "id": 402805327,
                "product_field_id": 88406,
                "value": "ptkG9EksjzVOEJNkm41Re3"
            }
        ],
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 714704881,
                "title": "",
                "product_id": 429947870,
                "sku": null,
                "barcode": null,
                "dimensions": null,
                "available": false,
                "image_ids": [],
                "image_id": null,
                "weight": null,
                "created_at": "2024-03-30T12:47:12.000+03:00",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-30T12:47:12.000+03:00",
                "quantity": 0,
                "cost_price": null,
                "cost_price_in_site_currency": null,
                "price_in_site_currency": "0.0",
                "base_price": "0.0",
                "old_price": null,
                "price": "0.0",
                "base_price_in_site_currency": "0.0",
                "old_price_in_site_currency": null,
                "prices": [],
                "prices_in_site_currency": [],
                "variant_field_values": [
                    {
                        "id": 95118101,
                        "variant_field_id": 11800,
                        "value": "ptkG9EksjzVOEJNkm41Re3"
                    }
                ],
                "option_values": []
            }
        ],
        "product_bundle_components": []
    }
]
```

Пытаюсь достать "title" (да и в целом, любой другой) так:

```
 app.MapPost("/api/webhook", (WebHook_Get hook) =>
    {
        JsonValue[] json = hook.Get;

        WebHook_Title responseDeserializedClass = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebHook_Title>(json.ToString());
        string result = responseDeserializedClass.Title;

        return hook;
    });
```

---

```
public class WebHook_Title()
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

public class WebHook_Get()
    {
        public JsonValue[] Get { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот такую ошибку получаю:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to read parameter "WebHook_Title hook" from the request body as JSON.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to _FF.WebHooks.InS.WebHook_Title. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 5.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsObjectAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest request, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest request, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>g__TryReadBodyAsync|102_0(HttpContext httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean throwOnBadRequest, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.InvalidJsonRequestBody(HttpContext httpContext, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Exception exception, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>g__TryReadBodyAsync|102_0(HttpContext httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean throwOnBadRequest, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass102_2.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: `[]` - массив/коллекция, `{}` - объект (класс), `"Key": Value` - свойство с именем `Key` и типом подходящим под `Value`. Вот имея это, теперь смотрите на свой JSON, прям в самое начало, с чего начинается? `[{` -что это? Верно, **коллекция** классов. А вы во что десериализуете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Правильно понимаю, так нужно ?
`WebHook_Title responseDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WebHook_Title>>(json.ToString());`

Comment: Да, все, понял, спасибо большое